# How can I set element.onmouseover?

Tags: vbscript

I am new to VBScript. I want to change the image source on mouseover but I am unable to that.

My code is as follows:

```
<head>

<script language="vbscript">

'code.....(please use Sub as sub and Img1 as img1)

Sub img1_OnClick

Img1.src="imge1.jpeg"

End sub
'code ends....
</script>

</head>

<body>

<img name="img1" src="imge.jpeg" />

</body>

</html>
```

This code is not working. Can anyone suggest something better?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `OnClick`, which sounds like the wrong event, I'd suggest looking at the `OnMouseOver` event and possibly also the `OnMouseOut` event instead.

Comment: OnMouseOver also doesn't work really can't understand the problem?

Comment: @amit: Don't know much about VBScript in HTML, but [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z7ye5ke(v=VS.85).aspx) page might be useful.

Comment: finally got success in ie6 just had to enable debugging scripts via tool->internet options